# JSfiddle Javascript if else error on the else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, jsfiddle

I have been using JSfiddle.com a lot recently just to compile some fun little code and other stuff. However when I do if else statements (like the one below) I always get an error on the else. The error is: "Expected an assignment or function call instead saw an expression". Please look to see if I'm doing any thing wrong. Here is my code:

```
                   var name = prompt("What is your name?");
                   if (name == "Charles");
                   {
                   alert("Welcome master.");
                   } 
Error here:            else;
                   {
                   alert("You have been denied goodbye.");
                   }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error


Comment: ` else;` extra `;` here also in the `if (name == "Charles");` statement `if (name == "Charles")`

Comment: so i need to delete the semicolon?

Comment: yes you need to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semicolons matter:

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
if (name == "Charles")
{
    alert("Welcome master.");
} 
else
{
    alert("You have been denied goodbye.");
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh... so I simply need to delete the semicolon off the if statement and the else because it ends the if statement?

Comment: Yes. And even if you didn't have the else block, the if wouldn't work. That semicolon would make it always alert, no matter what name you entered.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
   var name = prompt("What is your name?");
   if (name == "Charles") {
       alert("Welcome master.");
   } else {
       alert("You have been denied goodbye.");
   }
```

You shouldn't have that semi-colon after if or else because semi-colons end/separate statements and the condition is just starting.

Comment: Okay I get that, but out of curiosity why?

Comment: Because semi colons end/separate statements and the condition is just starting.

Comment: You should make that comment part of the answer, it's a nice, concise explanation.